# Add leading zeros to integer section of filename

Tags: bash, sed, git-bash

I have folders of images with names like `HolidaySnapsJune-1.tif` , `HolidaySnapsMay-12.tif` and `HolidaySnaps2018-005.tif`

I want to add one leading 0 to the **integer section** of the filename if it is 2 digits long, and I want to add two leading 00s if it is just one digit long.

I have tried variations of

```
find . -name '*\_[0-9][0-9].tif' -exec sh -c '
for fpath do
  echo mv "$fpath" "${fpath%/*}/${fpath##*/}"
done' _ {} +
```

But these put the leading zeros in front of the full file name instead of in front of the integer section.

I would love to do this is a bash script which would recursively work on folders so it's important that the difference in names preceeding the '-' is ignored or worked-around.

I'm on Windows and just have access to whatever is built into `git-bash`so bash, sed, awk etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after looking through the answers submitted here and elsewhere on SO this is what I ame up with:

```
find . -name '*\-[0-9][0-9].tif' -exec sh -c '
for f do
  mv "$f" "${f//\-/\-0}";
  echo "$f"
done' _ {} +
```

This works on files with two digits in the integer section, bringing them up to 3 digits. For single digit files I alter slightly and run again.

One nice thing about this script is that it works on subfolders.

I do have to admit to not understanding it completely. I have no real idea why `done`is followed by  `' _ {} +` . I guess that's the next thing I'll have to look up :-).

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `rename.ul` command from `linux-utils`.

```
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

replaces the first occurence of `expression` by `replacement` in all names of files passed to the command.

Assuming your filenames contain exactly one hyphen `-`, you could simply run both of the following commands in a shell that supports the `**/*` glob syntax (alternatively, use `find` with the `-exec` option or something alike) to recursively rename all files:

```
rename.ul -- - -00  **/*-?.tif
rename.ul -- - -0  **/*-??.tif
```

There are several options to `rename.ul` to prevent you from accidentally renaming unintended files (Watch out! The consequences could be quite drastic):

```
-v, --verbose
       Show which files were renamed, if any.

-n, --no-act
       Do not make any changes; add --verbose to see what  would
       be made.

-i, --interactive
       Ask before overwriting existing files.
```

So you could either run the commands with the `-nv` options to perform a dry-run and see what changes the program would make, or add `-i` to be asked for confirmation each time a file would be renamed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Simon. Unfortunately I don't have access to the linux-utils on this system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use non-standard commands and write a small script, this would be one way to do it.

```sh
while read -r line; do
    num=$(sed 's/\..*//' <<<${line/*-})
    printf -v new_name '%s-%03d.%s' "${line/-*}" "${num}" "${line/*\.}"
    mv -v "${line}” "${new_name}"
done < <(printf '%s\n' HolidaySnapsJune-1.tif HolidaySnapsMay-12.tif)
```

Using `HolidaySnapsJune-1.tif` for explanation below:

- `${line/*-}` removes everything before the dash `-`= `1.tif`
- `${line/*\.}` removes everything besides the extension.
- `sed 's/\..*//' <<<${line/*-}` also removes everything after the first period `.`, so now we have simply `1`
- `'%s-%03d.%s'` the `%03d` part of that tells printf to print digits with leading zeroes up to 3 digits.

Used `while read` as it is easy to mockup with. You probably want to either use a `find` command or something such for the input to the loop.